# PostgreSQL queries from external IP causing high CPU load. Have I been hacked?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Since I few days I have noticed that on my Atlassian Software VM (running only Jira, BitBucket and Bamboo) PostgreSQL is causing very high load as seen in htop.

[image]

I then checked with

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

what is running on my system and found two weird entries below.

```
12405 | postgres    | 15526 |       10 | postgres   |                  | 114.86.94.107 |                 |       56033 | 2017-11-17 15:40:03.745147+00 | 2017-11-17 15:40:04.954341+00 | 2017-11-17 15:40:04.954341+00 | 2017-11-17 15:40:04.954343+00 |                 |            | active |             |      3202367 | select Fun020001 ('./x4000021328 &')
12405 | postgres    | 15539 |       10 | postgres   |                  | 114.86.94.107 |                 |       61953 | 2017-11-17 15:40:12.560015+00 | 2017-11-17 15:40:13.374722+00 | 2017-11-17 15:40:13.374722+00 | 2017-11-17 15:40:13.374724+00 |                 |            | active |             |      3202368 | select Fun020001 ('./ps3991599979 &')
```

The queries they're running seem weird to me

```
select Fun020001 ('./x4000021328 &')
select Fun020001 ('./ps3991599979 &')
```

I then found files named like the two above in

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/

-rwxrwxrwx 1 postgres postgres    14480 Nov 17 15:39 ps3991599979
-rwxrwxrwx 1 postgres postgres   496464 Nov 17 15:40 x4000021328
```

Do I assume correctly that my machine has been hacked? For now I have disabled remote connections and deleted the binaries. I also turned off the machine. Is there anything else I can do to prevent further abuse of my VM?

Comment: Look like someone used privilege elevation through postgres superuser account...  It would be interesting to see the Fun020001 code... probably it uses some of untrusted languages

Comment: As per any hack, treat the old disk as poisoned and move all services to new host, using verified data only.

Comment: I have burned the old machine, made a new one and restored an old backup onto it.

Comment: This is similar to: [CPU 100% usage caused by unknown postgres query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617329) on S.O. but unfortunately no hint on what exact vulnerability is being exploited here.

Comment: @DanielVérité  I've seen attempts at this cryptocurrency mining hack, in which the vulnerability is just a "postgres" account exposed to the internet with a bad password.  They could be using a different vulnerability here, but no reason to think it is more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1):

After using clamscan to investigate further it found another backdoor installed.

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/base/12405/2613: Win.Trojan.MSShellcode-6360729-0 FOUND
```

I also found out that PostgreSQL 9.6 has [a lot of vulnerabilties](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-336/product_id-575/Postgresql-Postgresql.html), but apt-get wouldn't find a newer version than 9.6. To upgrade to Version 10 you'll need to add

```
 deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ sid-pgdg-testing main 10
```

to your sources in order to upgrade via

```
 apt-get install postgresql-10
```

Comment: 9.6 is a major version, and so is 10 with the new version naming. To get the latests patch, have a look at 9.6.6.